# Now that Google Apps (the free version) is gone, is there another way to use Gmail with a custom domain

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, outlook

I really like Gmail, and I really wanted to get Google Apps for free. Now I have a domain but their free service. Is there any way for me to map my domain name to my Gmail account? I am using [Outlook with a custom domain](http://domains.live.com) but I want to get my emails in Gmail. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tip to Register Google-Apps Free for single user account.

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/google-app-mail-for-free/

Comment: Is this a permanent solution, because I get the feeling that this is a bug that will be fixed eventually

Comment: I am not sure about it. Only Google Apps Team can answer this.

Comment: When I first read this, I suspected that this was a bug in Google App Engine

Comment: Can you expand on that? What's there? Why should the user follow the link? What happens when the link stops working?

Comment: Not any more. :-( After creation of an account as described in the article, I get: *"30 days left for your Google Apps for Business trial to expire"*

Comment: Probably, you signed up for Google Apps for Business, not sure though. I'll check it